# Swagger: generate xml response with attributes

Tags: java, xml, rest, swagger

I need to provide swagger docs for an endpoint which produces xml instead of json.
The problem is that xml attributes in the documentation's example are not generated properly.

For instance:

```
public class Page {

@ApiModelProperty(required = true)
@XmlAttribute(required = true)
private String url;

}
```

will be generated as:

```
<page>
   <url>example</url>
</page>
```

instead of:

```
<page url="example"></page>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to represent it with the OpenAPI specification 2.0. For more details, have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/630).

It may be addressed in future versions of the specification.